# Why does the magnetic field decrease at a decreasing rate (and not linearly) as the distance from the centre of the wire increases

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current

The magnetic field  around a wire can be described by:

$B=μ0*I/(2*π*r)$ ,  when $r>R$

Where:

- $B$ is the magnetic field
- $μ0$ is the permeability of free space
- $r$ is the distance from the center of the wire
- $R$ is the radius of the wire
- $I$ is the current flowing through the wire

[image: Wire]

The graph showing the above relationship is given by the **red portion** (i.e. for $r>R$):
[image: graph]

Why isn't this **red** part of the graph linear (rather than curved)?

From the formula :

$B=μ0*I/(2*π*r)$ , when $r>R$

$B ∝  1/r$ , when $r>R$

So wouldn't this indicate an (inversely proportional) **linear** relationship between $B$ and $r$ (rather than the curved one shown in red)?

FYI: Not sure if this is relevent, but my book calls the graph a "rectangular parabola".

Comment: ...why *should* the red part be linear? It's not clear what exactly you're asking for here.

Comment: Maybe I need to learn a bit more maths but I thought B∝1/r means that B increases at the same rate that r decreases? Resulting in a linear graph?

Comment: The function $f(x) = 1/x$ is not a linear graph.

Comment: "Inversely proportional" is by no means linear. The red curve is a fragment of hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ACuriousMind . I assumed that because y=x was linear, y=1/x is linear but downward (but that is y=-x). I will have to go and read about what y=1/x actually is. Thanks for spotting my error.

Comment: Plot the function with a pencil, paper and a pocket calculator and you will see.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks, I just did that and it is now clear. Do I just close the question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, your question does not really have to do with the magnetic field, rather you are asking why the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not linear, "even though it is the inverse of a linear function."

The last statement is in quotes because it is not true. The confussion here is about the notion of inversion. The reason you are compelled to think the function should be linear is because $\frac{1}{x}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $x$. That is to say $\frac{1}{x} \cdot x = 1$. However, you are conflating two different notions of inverse, namely the multiplicative inverse and the inverse function.

You are correct that the *inverse function* of a line is also a line. But to define the inverse function, we do not ask "which function do we multiply $f(x)$ by to get 1," we ask which function, $g(x)$, do we compose with $f(x)$ such that

$$g(f(x)) = x .$$

You do have an interesting question here though, which is "why does the multiplicative inverse of every number greater than 1 fit between 0 and 1." The reason $\frac{1}{x}$ is not linear is because it is the map that takes a number to its multiplicative inverse, and the distance between the multiplicative inverse of $x$ and $x+1$ is $\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$, whilst the distance between $x$ and $x+1$ is, of course, $1$.

I hope a better mathematician can illuminate this further.